# Is it safe to generate client nonces using random number generator?

Tags: security, http, protocol

I am making HTTP calls on the client side and the server expects me to supply a client nonce. It needs to be 4 bytes long. I am planning to use this combination:

```
base64(parts of the MAC address + random bits generated by RNG)
```

Given that the protocol is created by experts (thus its security is not to be questioned), is my nonce calculation acceptable in your view ?

Comment: Use a CSPRNG if you aren't using one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator

Comment: It depends.  What are the consequences of this nonce being spoofed?  MACs are software configurable.  They're not "burned into the hardware" of a NIC -- a least not for the last decade or more.  You can change the MAC of a NIC as easily as opening a dialog and typing what you want it to be.  So, if it's seriously bad if this thing is spoofed, then you shouldn't delude yourself into thinking a MAC is somehow secure by virtue of being theoretically globally unique (it's not even close).

Comment: If you are using the MAC Address then the RNG isn't very random.  You do understand this right?  If this semi-random noise is not used for security then it should be fine.

Comment: Random 32 bit numbers collide pretty often. If you want uniqueness, use at least 120 bits.

Answer (score 1):

From a cryptographic protocol perspective what is usually important about a nonce (number used once) is its one-timeness. Having it generated with a (P)RNG is rather a matter of convenience. If a cryptographic protocol has specific entropy requirements on a nonce or assumes it to be otherwise cryptographically secure in some way - that would be typically known, communicated or stated upfront, because that isn't a standard expectation.

> I am making HTTP calls on the client side and the server expects me to supply a client nonce

This is a typical scenario for the prevention of a replay attack - relying on the one-timeness of certain parts of the client input.

> I am planning to use this combination:
>       base64(parts of the MAC address + random bits generated by RNG)

When you rely on parts of the MAC address as an input to a linear transformation, you are setting yourself for an increased probability of the nonce repeating, increasing the chance of a successful replay attack, or alternatively you increase the chance of an adversary guessing your next nonce in advance, making her job easier in a sense.

Notwithstanding, in an expert chosen cryptographic protocol (as assumed in the question) it will be more common for both parties to choose a nonce, mitigating inadequate choice of a nonce by only one party. With a server nonce and a client nonce, establishing a communication frequently looks like this,

- server -> client: [snonce, challenge]
- client ->server:  [cnonce, f(cnonce, snonce, challenge)]

and when you don't chose `cnonce` adequately, or don't have a client nonce at all, an adversary can observe `f(snonce, challenge)` responses, where all the inputs are chosen by it, when it masquerades as a server. This can at times deteriorate to a chosen plaintext attack.

I suggest that you simplify the nonce to be along the lines of,

```
cnonce = base64(random bits generated by RNG)
```

where you RNG has sufficient entropy. And if you need repeatability for test purposes, eg if you run your protocol client side tests in a farm on different boxes you can:

```
seed(RNG, parts of the MAC address)
cnonce = base64(random bits generated by RNG)
```

That way your tests on every box will be amenable for debugging.